# Is it possible to parallelize this efficiently?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize this code below but I'm new to parallelization in Python. The goal is to have a parallel process for each iteration of i. For one iteration of i,  it takes around 10  minutes and there are 247 Periods I need to do this for.

```
periodMisIdx_CTrad = []
periodADF_CTrad = []

for i in range(numPeriods):    
    firstMisIdx = []
    lowestADF = []

    for j in range(periodNumAssets[i]):
        init = normRets_np[i][0][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
        form = normRets_np[i][1][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
        trade = normRets_np[i][2][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
            
        # init       
        initCopC, _ = fitCvines(init, structures)
            
        # form
        misIdxForm = compute_mispricing_index(form,initCopC)
        adftests = []
        for k in range(len(structures)):
            temp = adfuller(misIdxForm[k])
            adftests.append(temp[0])
        minadf = min(adftests)
        structNum = adftests.index(minadf)
        formCopC = [pv.Vinecop(form, structure = pv.CVineStructure(structures[structNum]))]
        misIdxForm = misIdxForm[structNum]
        
        # trade
        misIdxTrade = np.squeeze(compute_mispricing_index(trade, formCopC))
            
        firstMisIdx.append( [misIdxForm, misIdxTrade] )
        lowestADF.append(minadf)
    
    periodMisIdx_CTrad.append(firstMisIdx)
    periodADF_CTrad.append(lowestADF)
```

Now i tried parallelizing this and I ran it for i = 2 periods, and it took about 20minutes so it actually doesn't speed up anything. This is the code i tried:

```
numPeriods = 2

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool

def process_period(i):
    firstMisIdx = []
    lowestADF = []

    for j in range(periodNumAssets[i]):

        init = normRets_np[i][0][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
        form = normRets_np[i][1][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
        trade = normRets_np[i][2][:,Q_trad_new[i][j]]
            
        # init       
        initCopC, _ = fitCvines(init, structures)
            
        # form
        misIdxForm = compute_mispricing_index(form,initCopC)
        adftests = []
        for k in range(len(structures)):
            temp = adfuller(misIdxForm[k])
            adftests.append(temp[0])
        minadf = min(adftests)
        structNum = adftests.index(minadf)
        formCopC = [pv.Vinecop(form, structure = pv.CVineStructure(structures[structNum]))]
        misIdxForm = misIdxForm[structNum]
        
        # trade
        misIdxTrade = np.squeeze(compute_mispricing_index(trade, formCopC))
            
        firstMisIdx.append( [misIdxForm, misIdxTrade] )
        lowestADF.append(minadf)

    return firstMisIdx, lowestADF

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    

    results = pool.map(process_period, range(numPeriods))


    periodMisIdx_CTrad = [result[0] for result in results]
    periodADF_CTrad = [result[1] for result in results]
```

Is there a mistake I am overlooking that could speed up the process? When I check the CPU utilisation it's only between 8-12%. I have 12 cores and 24GB of GPU memory by the way.

Comment: As usual: have you measured your code using a profiling tool to see where it's spending most of its time?

Comment: You have `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`. That is *not* multiprocessing; that is multithreading, which, because of contention for the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), is not suitable for CPU-intensive processing.

Comment: I would try to define the procedure that is to be done in an iteration in a function and then use joblib: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ to parallelise the code. As long as each iteration is independent of the others, this should be a piece of cake.

Comment: @AKX i ran the profile and it said that the functions threading.py:556(wait) and threading.py:280(wait) have the highest cumtime. Not sure what that tells me though

Comment: @Leo I implemented joblib and now it's working super fast. It finishes 12 periods in about 17 minutes which is a lot faster already. Thank you very much, that solves my problem! CPU utilization is at 67% . I assume I could make it even faster using my GPU somehow. Any tips on how I could start learning that? I believe CUDAtools does some powerful stuff with Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: Note that AFAIK joblib uses multiprocessing by default (modified version which should not strongly impact performance), not multithreading. This might explain the performance gap due to the GIL as mentioned by Booboo.

Comment: GPUs operate completely differently compared to CPUs. You cannot just run that on GPUs as it is. It require a deep modification of the code and I expect this to be far from being simple here due to operations like `pv.Vinecop`. IDK what is supposed to be `compute_mispricing_index` and so if it is simple to port it on GPUs. What makes GPU hard to use efficiently is that the code must be converted to SIMT-friendly kernels and needed data should be copied on the GPU. Some codes are inherently not SIMT-friendly and so are not suited to GPUs. It depends of the actual exact code.

Comment: A naive simple approach is simply to use cupy (Numpy implementation using CUDA internally for most functions) so to use Nvidia GPUs, but it may or may not be faster (it can be much slower if you perform many operations on small arrays). I advise to optimize your code on CPU first, then check if the code is SIMT-friendly, then lean CUDA and how GPUs works, and only then try to port the code on GPUs.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for your insights, that's a great starting point for the future

Comment: @UncleRandy Yeah, that profiling result doesn't help much. Profile the single-process/single-thread version so you'll know what to optimize most.